# How to animate parent container after hiding one child and showing another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to animate a parent container (which is essentially just a border) after hiding a child input box and displaying a different child textarea simultaneously, and vice-versa. jQuery UI is what I am using.

Both child elements are of the same width, just different heights. The height of the textarea is determined by the 'rows' attribute.

Instead of the default behavior of the parent container resizing instantly, I'm trying to get it to animate the transition in height.

Pretty confident this is not a duplicate question.

```
<!-- Blue-bordered container -->
<div class="input-group text-info">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-lg text-info"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Either an 'input' is displayed... -->
    <input type="text">
    <!-- ...or a 'textarea'  -->
    <textarea rows="5" style="display:none"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question may be improved by including steps or code you have tried. It would be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour or read how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Stack Overflow is to get help or guidance from the community, not to have someone write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Here is an example using `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` options.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".input-group-text").click(function() {
    var p = $(this).parent().parent();
    var hidden = $(":hidden", p);
    if (hidden.is("input")) {
      console.log("Hide TextArea");
      $("textarea", p).fadeOut(100, function() {
        p.animate({
          height: "2.5em"
        }, 600);
        $("input", p).fadeIn(100);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Hide Input");
      $("input", p).fadeOut(100, function() {
        p.animate({
          height: "7.5em"
        }, 600);
        $("textarea", p).fadeIn(100);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.text-info {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .4em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input-group text-info" style="height: 2.5em;">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-lg text-info"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="text">
  <textarea rows="5" style="display:none"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Update**

You can use `.animate()` to adjust specific styles. So to update the box, apply a `height` value to it and then use Animate to change it at a specific speed.

**Example**

```
$(".text-info").animate({
  height: "7.5em"
}, 600);
```

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
>
> - properties - An object of CSS properties and values that the animation will move toward.
> - duration (default: 400) - A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

See More: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not being clear. You got the right idea about switching between 'input' and 'textarea', but it's not those elements that I need effects on. It's the input group (blue border) that I want to slowly resize/animate when the child elements are switched. Right now, you can see it just instantly resizes once the toggle occurs.

Comment: @Adam for this, you then need to apply a `height` value to the box. then you can `.animate()` the change of height.